# Disqus API adding comment

Tags: php, json, api, disqus

I'm trying to submit a comment to my blog from another site via the [Disqus API](http://disqus.com/api/docs/).

I'm using [create](http://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/create/) to submit a comment. I'm using the API console to try it out. I added an author_id, author_email, comment but I'm not sure what to add to `thread` or `forum`. I tried my post id (256) http://www.myblog.com/?p=`256` but that returns..

```
{
  "code": 2, 
  "response": "Invalid argument, 'thread': User does not have write privileges on thread '256'"
}
```

Can anyone who used the API please tell me how to create comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the default value that 'thread' is looking for is a Disqus internal thread ID (rather than the Wordpress ID in your case). However, you can use the custom `disqus_identifier` that is set via the Wordpress plugin (look for that value in the source code of your blog post), or the URL associated with the thread if you pass `forum=YOUR_SHORTNAME` in addition.

So here's how you can select a thread:

```
// Example using Disqus internal ID
POST https://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/create.json
(your arguments)...
thread=12345678

// Example using disqus_identifier
POST https://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/create.json 
(your arguments)...
thread=ident:256 http://www.myblog.com/?p=256 // This is the schema used in the WP plugin
forum=YOUR_SHORTNAME

// Example using URL (this is the least reliable)
POST https://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/create.json 
(your arguments)...
thread=link:http://www.myblog.com/some_slug
forum=YOUR_SHORTNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the 'user' who i presume registered the application thats calling the API write permissions.

See here: http://disqus.com/api/docs/permissions/